# Expand parent div without scrolling when child div button clicks

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have parent and child div tags. Child div having button. Button retrieves data from another page. When i clicks on button data successfully displaying, but with vertical scrolling.

How can i expand parent div without scrolling based on child div? Here is my code.

Any help Please!!

```js
(function($) {
    $(function() {
        $("#accordion > div").accordion({ 
            header: "h3", 
            collapsible: true  
        });
    })
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<!-- Parent Div -->
<div id="accordion">   
    <!-- Child Div -->
    <div>
        <h3>REVIEWS</h3>
        <div>
            <!-- Button which is retrieving data from another page -->
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_review') ?>  
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

The out put

[image]

Comment: Must see the css on parent divs. You should give a look at the `overflow` property

Comment: You want me to provide css? There is 20 lines of css. May i provide here or somewhere else?

Comment: only `#accordion` properties

Comment: I don't have css for #accordian

Comment: .ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header {display: block; cursor: pointer;
 position: relative;margin: 6px 0 0;padding: .5em .5em .5em .7em;
 min-height: 0; /* support: IE7 */ font-size: 15px;}
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-icons {padding-left: 2.2em;}
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-icons .ui-accordion-icons {padding-left: 2.2em;}
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header .ui-accordion-header-icon {position: absolute; left: .5em; top: 50%; margin-top: -8px;}
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-content {border-top: 0 none;font-size: 14px;
    overflow: auto;padding: 5px;text-align: justify;}

Comment: `.ui-accordion-content { overflow: auto;` What if you replace this property ?

Comment: when i remove overflow:auto it is displaying without scrolling, but, parent div is not expanding

Comment: Look the documentation on the accordion. Maybe you will find the solution http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-heightStyle

Comment: This is not working. Any help please!!!!!

Comment: Hurrey! Finally i did it, i just given height:auto !important to parent div

Answer (score 0):

`overflow-y:auto;` and `max-height:100%;` might achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Hurrey! Finally i did it, i just given height:auto !important to parent div